# Creating reminder emails from google sheets, from data collected from google form using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Email reminders (1, 3, 7 days before requested date & time) not sent out based on Google Sheets data.
It needs to reference the nature of request (deployment/removal), number of device, requested date, requested time. Also, sent to 4 email addressess in total, 3 admin addressess and 1 respondent email address Also, reminder emails to be sent out on form submission, and on form edits validating number of days before requested date and time again by the App Script.

The email subject is correct, "Reminder - Upcoming service request", but not the content of the email.

The intended content of the email to be expected.

This is a reminder for the upcoming (Deployment/Removal) service request.
Date: DD/MM/YYYY (Requested Date)
Time: HH:MM (Requested Time - 24hrs format, GMT +8)

Please contact your PIC or XX @ "phone number", "email" if you have any queries.

```
// Triggered on form submission
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  sendReminders();
}

// Set up a form submission trigger
function createFormSubmitTrigger() {
  // Delete existing triggers to avoid duplicates
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  // Create a new form submission trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

// Function to send reminders based on form submission
function sendReminders() {
  // Hard-coded email addresses
  var recipientEmails = ["recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com", "recipient3@example.com"];

  // Get the active spreadsheet and sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Assuming that the requested date is in Column F, requested time is in Column G, type is in Column D, and email is in Column C (adjust accordingly)
  var requestedDateColumn = 6;  // Change this to the correct column index
  var requestedTimeColumn = 4;  // Change this to the correct column index for "Requested Time"
  var typeColumn = 3;  // Change this to the correct column index
  var emailColumn = 2;  // Change this to the correct column index

  // Get the data range excluding the header row
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());

  // Get values in the requested date, time, type, and email columns
  var requestData = dataRange.getValues();

  // Iterate through requested dates to send reminders
  for (var i = 0; i < requestData.length; i++) {
    var requestedDate = new Date(requestData[i][requestedDateColumn - 1]);
    var requestedTime = parseTime(requestData[i][requestedTimeColumn - 1]); // Get requested time
    var type = requestData[i][typeColumn - 1]; // Get type
    var emailAddress = requestData[i][emailColumn - 1]; // Get email address

    // Combine requested date and time into a single Date object
    var combinedDateTime = new Date(requestedDate);
    combinedDateTime.setHours(requestedTime.getHours());
    combinedDateTime.setMinutes(requestedTime.getMinutes());

    // Calculate the date 7 days before the combined date and time
    var reminderDate = new Date(combinedDateTime);
    reminderDate.setDate(reminderDate.getDate() - 7);

    // Check if the day is a working day (Monday to Friday)
    while (reminderDate.getDay() === 0 || reminderDate.getDay() === 6) {
      reminderDate.setDate(reminderDate.getDate() - 1);
    }

    // Get the current date
    var currentDate = new Date();

    // Check if the reminder date is in the future
    if (currentDate < reminderDate) {
      // Determine the appropriate message based on the type (deployment or removal)
      var messageType = (type === 'Deployment') ? "Deployment" : "Removal";
      var message = "This is a reminder for the upcoming " + messageType + " on " + combinedDateTime.toLocaleString();

      // Send an email reminder using MailApp.sendEmail
      var subject = "Reminder: Upcoming Service Request";
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: subject,
        body: message,
        name: '', // Add your name here
        replyTo: '', // Add your email here
        cc: '', // Add CC email if needed
        bcc: '' // Add BCC email if needed
      });

      // Log email details
      Logger.log("Sending email to: " + emailAddress);
      Logger.log("Subject: " + subject);
      Logger.log("Message: " + message);

      // You can add additional actions here, such as marking the reminder as sent in the sheet
    }
  }

  // Send reminders to hard-coded email addresses
for (var i = 0; i < recipientEmails.length; i++) {
  var recipient = recipientEmails[i];
  var subject = "Reminder: Upcoming Service Request";

  // Determine the appropriate message based on the type (deployment or removal)
  var messageType = "Service Request"; // Default message type for hard-coded emails
  var message = "This is a reminder for an upcoming " + messageType + ".";

  // Log details for hard-coded emails
  Logger.log("Sending email to: " + recipient);
  Logger.log("Subject: " + subject);
  Logger.log("Message: " + message);

  // Send an email reminder using MailApp.sendEmail
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: message,
    name: '', // Add your name here
    replyTo: '', // Add your email here
    cc: '', // Add CC email if needed
    bcc: '' // Add BCC email if needed
  });
}

    // Log email details
    Logger.log("Sending email to: " + recipient);
    Logger.log("Subject: " + subject);
    Logger.log("Message: " + message);
  }

// Helper function to parse time from time string or integer
function parseTime(time) {
  if (typeof time === 'string') {
    var timeParts = time.split(":");
    if (timeParts.length > 1) {
      var hours = parseInt(timeParts[0], 10);
      var minutes = parseInt(timeParts[1], 10);
      return new Date(2000, 0, 1, hours, minutes); // Use an arbitrary date (year 2000) for consistent time calculations
    }
  } else if (typeof time === 'number') {
    var hours = Math.floor(time / 100);
    var minutes = time % 100;
    return new Date(2000, 0, 1, hours, minutes); // Use an arbitrary date (year 2000) for consistent time calculations
  }

  return new Date(); // Return current date if parsing fails
}

// Set up a daily time-driven trigger
function createDailyTrigger() {
  // Delete existing triggers to avoid duplicates
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  // Create a new daily trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendReminders')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1) // Run the function every day
    .create();
}

// Run the createFormSubmitTrigger function to create the form submission trigger
createFormSubmitTrigger();
```

Email received from current AppScript as below,

Subject: "Reminder: Upcoming Service Request"
Content: "This is a reminder for an upcoming Service Request."

Answer (score 0):

In your `sendReminders()` function, you have `var message = "This is a reminder for an upcoming " + messageType + ".";`

then you log some stuff, and then write

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: message,
    name: '', // Add your name here
    replyTo: '', // Add your email here
    cc: '', // Add CC email if needed
    bcc: '' // Add BCC email if needed
  });
```

This will always just have the content be in the form
`"This is a reminder for an upcoming " + messageType + "."`

If you wanted to have it in the format

> This is a reminder for the upcoming (Deployment/Removal) service
> request. Date: DD/MM/YYYY (Requested Date) Time: HH:MM (Requested Time
> - 24hrs format, GMT +8)
> Please contact your PIC or XX @ "phone number", "email" if you have any queries.

where you add the date and contact info, you have to append that to your message variable.